# Let $A$ be a Dedekind domain and $p$ be a prime ideal in $A$ then how to prove that $A/p^n \equiv A_p/p^nA_p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, valuation-theory, dedekind-domain

Let $A$ be a Dedekind domain and $p$ be a prime ideal in $A$ then how to prove that $A/p^n \equiv A_p/p^nA_p$.

Clearly, $A_p$ is a D.V.R. 
Considering the map $\phi : A/p^n \to A_p/p^nA_p$ s.t $\phi(a)= \frac a1+p^nA_p$.

This well defined and ring homomorphism is fine.

But how to show that $\frac a1+p^nA_p=0$ then $\frac a1= \frac xs$ where $x \in p^n$ this implies $a \in p^n$?? That is how to show $\phi$ is injective?

Then how to prove $\phi$ is surjective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is Dedekind, it has Krull dimension one, i.e.  non-zero prime ideals are maximal. There results that  $\mathfrak p^n$ is contained in the sole maximal ideal $\mathfrak p$, and thence $A/\mathfrak p^n$  is a *local* ring of dimension $0$. It is therefore equal to its localisation at $\mathfrak p/\mathfrak p^n$, and
$$A/\mathfrak p^n=\bigl(A/\mathfrak p^n\bigr)_{\mathfrak p/\mathfrak p^n}\simeq A_{\mathfrak p}/\mathfrak p^nA_{\mathfrak p}.$$

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit. I have understood that $p^n \subseteq p$ and $p$ is maximal. Then what?

Comment: $A/p^n$ is a local ring of dimension $0$ is also fine. Next conclusion is drawn from where?

Comment: It is the only maximal ideal that contains $\mathfrak p^n$ (by the *avoidance lemma*) so that the quotient ring is local, which implies  the classes of elements not in $\mathfrak p$ are units in the quotient.

Comment: Don't forget that $S^{-1}R$, when $S$ consists of units in $R$, is isomorphic to $R$, as are any solutions of a universal problem.

Comment: And why $(A/p^n)_{p/p^n} \cong A_p/p^nA_p$?

Comment: That is because of a basic result on ring of fractions : if $S'$ is the  canonical  image of $S$ in $A/I$, the $S'^{-1}(A/I)\simeq S^{-1}A/S^{-1}I$.

Comment: One more question $A/p^n$ has dimension $0$ or $1$? Because $0$ is also a prime ideal in $A/p^n$.

Comment: No: $0$ is not prime, except if $n=1$, since $A/\mathfrak p^n$ is not an integral domain (it has nilpotent elements).

Comment: Yeah sorry, my mistake